# To Rails 3 Routing from Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, actionmailer, activation

I am following this tutorial on sending activation email:

http://www.slideshare.net/JamesEdwardGrayII/sending-email-with-rails

I am fairly certain this was done with rails 2 and the routing has been a little problematic for me.

```
routes.rb:

map.activate "activate/:token", :controller => "activations", :action => "create"
```

enables:

```
activate_url(:token => @user.perishable_token, :host => "localhost:3000")
```

So that `localhost:3000/:token` url is sent for the user to activate.

In order to make it work for rails 3, I have tried the following:

```
match 'activate/:token' => 'activations#create'
match 'activate/:token', :to => 'activations#create'
```

but `activate_url` isn't working. I'd appreciate some input. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `routes.rb` add a `:as => 'activate'` to your `match` method like this:

`match 'activate/:token' => 'activations#create', :as => 'activate'` and if you are only using GET/POST I'd change the route to this:

**For GET:**

`get 'activate/:index' => 'activations#create', :as => 'activate'`

**or for POST**

`post 'activate/:index' => 'activations#create', :as => 'activate'`